# How to get current window time in sliding window?

Tags: java, real-time, apache-storm, sliding-window

I'm using sliding window by storm implementation:

[From Here](http://storm.apache.org/releases/1.0.0/Windowing.html)

This is my topology:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    TopologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder();

    builder.setSpout("rabbitSpout", new RabbitMQSpout());
    builder.setBolt("filterBolt", new FilteringBolt()).shuffleGrouping("rabbitSpout");

    builder.setBolt("HourStatisticsBolt", new SlidingWindowStatisticsBolt()
            .withWindow(new BaseWindowedBolt.Duration(60, TimeUnit.MINUTES),
                    new BaseWindowedBolt.Duration(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
            .withTimestampField("timestamp")).shuffleGrouping("filterBolt");
```

In my SlidingWindowStatisticsBolt's execute method I'd like to get the timestamp at which windows start or end. In my bolt how can I get the windows length and the sliding duration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using event time (`withTimestampField`) the windows are computed based on periodic watermarks. Right now the window start/end time is not exposed in the TupleWindow.

In the latest master branch of storm, the [TupleWindow](https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/master/storm-core/src/jvm/org/apache/storm/windowing/Window.java#L54) has a `getTimestamp` method which returns the window end timestamp and works for both processing and event time based windows. This will be available in the future release of storm (2.0 release). If you would like this to be back ported and made available in the next 1.x release you can file a JIRA [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/STORM)